# test email is working but not sending email with wp mail

Tags: wp-mail

```
wp_mail($emails, 'New Contact Enquiry | ' . $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments)
```

but getting this error.

WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [0] => SMTP Error: data not accepted. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [to] => Array ( [0] => noreply@capitalsmart.com.au ) [subject] => New Contact Enquiry | Government Project Enquiry [message] =>

Sender Email :jon@yahoo.com

Sender Contact: :21312312312

Message :tersrtrt

[headers] => Array ( [Reply-To] => sales@varcon.com.au [MIME-Version] => 1.0 ) [attachments] => Array ( [0] => ) ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Check with your email host regarding the "data not accepted" error.

This could be for a number of reasons.  Based on what you posted, the most likely reason is trying to use a different "from" address than the account's actual address.  For example, using the "admin@mydomain.com" account to send from "sales@mydomain.com".  In other words, "jon@yahoo.com" as a sender is being rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Error due to headers section of email body.I have removed the headers="MIME-VERSION" and its working fine.